# updateChildren not updating the array of images, its overwriting the exist array(url) data firebase android

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

updateChildren not updating the array of images, its overwriting the exist array(url) data firebase android. I want to add some more images to existing url array in firebase.
 This is my firebase structure

```
  Blog--
     pushid--
       "name": xxxx
        "url"
             -- 0: "first image"
                1: "second image"
```

I want to update(add some more images to existing url array . Im using updatechildren() but its overwriting the existing images

```
for (String photo : selectedImages) {
                    blogimages = new ArrayList<>();
                    Uri file = Uri.fromFile(new File(photo));
                    Bitmap bitmap = null;
                    try {
                        bitmap = decodeSampledBitmapFromUri(file, mMaxDimension, mMaxDimension);


                        StorageReference photoRef = mstorageReference.child("images/" + file.getLastPathSegment());
                        uploadTask = photoRef.putBytes(byteArray);

                        uploadTask.addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {



                            }
                        }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                                Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                                blogimages.add(downloadUrl.toString());

                                Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();
                                childUpdates.put("url", blogimages);

                                HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();

                                params.put("url", blogimages);
                                uploads.child(post_key).child("url").updateChildren(params).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                            Toast.makeText(UpdatePost.this, "Post updated..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                            MainActivity.loaded = true;
                                            Intent i = new Intent(UpdatePost.this, MainActivity.class);
                                            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                                            startActivity(i);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                        Toast.makeText(UpdatePost.this, "Failed to post the blog.. Try again later", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }
                                });

                            }
                        });
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Can't find file to resize: " + e.getMessage());
                        FirebaseCrash.report(e);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Error occurred during resize: " + e.getMessage());
                        FirebaseCrash.report(e);
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not the way `updateChildren()` works.  `updateChildren()` will completely overwrite the content for all child fields that you specify.  It doesn't "push" array elements at all, or do any other array-like operations.  If you want to append to an array, you're going to have to read the contents of the array from the database, then add the element, then write it back out.

Note that Firestore is different in that it has an arrayUnion operation to append non-unique array elements to an array type field.